# Python object initialization and order of method evaluation

Tags: python, oop

Asking just out of curiosity:

Intuitively, I would tend to think that the code below would fail because the `__init__` function calls `somefunc` to populate `somevar` before the function was defined in the object's body, as would be the case for functions within a module.

Could you explain why this code actually works?

Thanks,

```
class someobj:
    def __init__(self):
        self.somevar = self.somefunc()
    def somefunc(self):
        return 'some_value'

obj = someobj()
print(obj.somevar)
```

Comment: Your `__init__` won't actually be evaluated until you create a `someobj` instance reference.  By that point, `self.somefunc` would have been fully defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `def` assigns the function code, variables etc to its name, but doesn't run the internal code. [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions).

The interpretater looks at this script and says

1. I'll define a class (basically a namespace)
2. Inside the class, I'll DEFINE class.init
3. Another define call; I'll DEFINE class.somefumc
4. Now the init is called by the constructor and the somefunc method is already defined.

Comment: Very clear, thanks a lot for this!